# Show that these two expressions for the oracle transformation are equivalent

Tags: quantum-algorithms, quantum-gate, oracles, phase-kickback

Suppose $x \in \{0,1\}^n$. The standard way to make a query is with an oracle $O_x$ that given an input $|i,b \rangle $ returns $|i,b \oplus x_i \rangle$. Via the phase kick-back trick, this can be used to make another type of query $O_{x}^{''}$ such that $O_{x}^{''}|i\rangle=(-1)^{x_i}|i\rangle$. This is easily seen by passing to the $|+\rangle, |- \rangle$ basis. How can it be seen that the converse is true i.e. that with a query of the latter type (and perhaps some ancillary qubit or transformation) one can implement a query of the former type?

Comment: Are you sure that this is even possible?  I have a vague memory from long ago that is was not clear how to go from a phase to a normal oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we express the action of $O_x$ on the basis $\mid i, \pm \rangle$ instead of $\mid i , b \rangle$

\begin{eqnarray*}
O_x \mid i , + \rangle = \mid i , + \rangle\\
O_x \mid i , - \rangle = (-1)^{x_i} \mid i , - \rangle\\
\end{eqnarray*}

Because we say auxiliary qubits must be started and ended with $0$,

\begin{eqnarray*}
O_x'' &=& (1 \otimes S_x H) O_x (1 \otimes H S_x)
\end{eqnarray*}

where the $1 \otimes H S_x$ conjugation takes care of turning the auxiliary from $0$ to $-$ and back.

Be careful about what $O_x''$ does. It does the desired $(-1)^{x_i}$ only when the ancilla is in $0$ as it is supposed to be. If the auxiliary is in $1$ instead, $O_x''$ acts like the identity.

\begin{eqnarray*}
O_x'' \mid i , 0 \rangle &=& (-1)^{x_i} \mid i, 0 \rangle\\
O_x'' \mid i , 1 \rangle &=& \mid i, 1 \rangle\\
\end{eqnarray*}

Solve for $O_x$

\begin{eqnarray*}
O_x &=& (1 \otimes H S_x) O_x'' (1 \otimes S_x H)
\end{eqnarray*}

See what it does on $\mid i , + \rangle$ and $\mid i, - \rangle$

\begin{eqnarray*}
(1 \otimes H S_x) O_x'' (1 \otimes S_x H) \mid i, + \rangle &=& (1 \otimes H S_x) O_x'' \mid i, 1 \rangle\\
&=& (1 \otimes H S_x) \mid i, 1 \rangle\\
&=& \mid i, + \rangle\\
(1 \otimes H S_x) O_x'' (1 \otimes S_x H) \mid i, - \rangle &=& (1 \otimes H S_x) O_x'' \mid i, 0 \rangle\\
&=& (1 \otimes H S_x) (-1)^{x_i} \mid i, 0 \rangle\\
&=& (-1)^{x_i} \mid i , - \rangle\\
\end{eqnarray*}

This matches with what we wanted for $O_x$ in the first two lines.

Edit:

\begin{eqnarray*}
O_x \mid i, + \rangle &=& O_x \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (\mid i, 0 \rangle + \mid i, 1 \rangle)\\
&=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (O_x \mid i, 0 \rangle + O_x \mid i, 1 \rangle)\\
&=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (\mid i, 0+x_i \rangle + O_x \mid i, 1+x_i \rangle)\\
&=& \mid i, + \rangle
\end{eqnarray*}

For the last equality, the two summands either swap or they don't depending on $x_i$. Similarly with -

\begin{eqnarray*}
O_x \mid i, - \rangle &=& O_x \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (\mid i, 0 \rangle - \mid i, 1 \rangle)\\
&=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (O_x \mid i, 0 \rangle - O_x \mid i, 1 \rangle)\\
&=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (\mid i, 0+x_i \rangle - O_x \mid i, 1+x_i \rangle)\\
\end{eqnarray*}

so if $x_i=0$ there is no swap of terms and the result is $\mid i, - \rangle$. If $x_i=1$, there is a swap of terms and the result is $- \mid i, - \rangle$. This can be put together by saying $O_x \mid i, - \rangle = (-1)^{x_i} \mid i , - \rangle$

Comment: How does this explain how to get from a phase oracle $|x\rangle \to (-1)^{f(x)} |x\rangle$ back to a normal oracle?  Your $O_x$ is quite different!

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. I don't understand how it matches what we expect from $O_x$ because $O_x$ is not supposed to ever multiply $|i\rangle$ by $-1$.

Comment: Yes, but what I need instead is $O_x|i,b\rangle=|i,b\oplus x_i \rangle$. The content of your edit is basically the hypothesis.

Comment: You can now see the rest of the answer. It was a this is what we want, write down a formula using O_x" and then check that it did the correct behavior on a basis.

Comment: @AHusain What is $S_x$? how do you find  such  operator

Answer (score 2):

You are given a quantum circuit for $U$ compiled into the H/CNOT/T gateset. Derive a controlled version of $U$ by adding a control qubit $q$, replacing every H with a controlled H, every CNOT with a CCNOT, and every T with a controlled T. In all cases the new control goes on the $q$.

Recompile the modified gates down into the H/CNOT/T gate set. Prepend and append the circuit with a Hadamard on $q$. You now have a circuit that toggles $q$ when a -1 eigenstate of $U$ is input and leaves $q$ alone when a +1 eigenstate of $U$ is input.

In short:

- Circuit $C$ implements $(-1)^{f(x)}$
- Derive controlled $C$ implementing $(-1)^{q \cdot f(x)}$
- Switch control basis from Z to X, achieving $q \mathrel{\oplus} = f(x)$

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply. Do you think the result is achievable also without using controlled $U$?

Comment: And also: control basis Z is $|+\rangle,|-\rangle$ and X is $|0\rangle,|1\rangle$?

Comment: @Karl You need the control in order to change the unobservable global phase into an observable relative phase. In practice you won't need to literally control every single operation; there's usually more efficient ways. This is just the simplest way to introduce a control.